# Codename One Android Build Error - android.licenseKey

Tags: java, android, codenameone

When I'm trying to do an Android build, it's giving me this error:

Exception: java.lang.Exception: android.licenseKey must be defined in the build hints, grab the key from the "Service & Apis" section in the android dev portal

I haven't changed the Android certificate since I started the project. The main thing I've done since the Android builds were working was install the Bouncy Castle API and added some code related to that, and added the Android Billing xpermisson. Is there any further troubleshooting I can do to see what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

You added In App Purchase usage. This means we need a base 64 key from Google play to encrypt our communication with Google Play.